# how to scanf inputs, 3 at a time, process them, then continue scanf the rest of input in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3


void assign(double A[][COLS], double nrows);
void print(double A[][COLS], double nrows);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    double A[ROWS][COLS];
    assign(A, ROWS);
    print(A, ROWS);
    return 0;
}


void
assign(double A[][COLS], double nrows){
    double mass, velocity_terminal, area;
    while(scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area)==3){
    int i;
    for (i= 0; i<nrows; i++){
                A[i][0]= mass;
                A[i][1]= velocity_terminal;
                A[i][2]= area;
    }
        }
    }

void
print(double A[][COLS], double nrows){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<nrows; j++){
            printf("%5lf",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

i'm sorry for the formatting. the objective is to arrange inputs in a 2 dimensional array. i'm trying to read the input that's piped from a text file in the prompt. so taking 3 at a time and assigning them to places . the code above only put the last 3 inputs into the array.

Comment: First write down code properly so that we can visualize it properly.

Comment: Note: The spaces in `"%lf, %lf, %lf"` do not affect the results.  `"%lf"` will consume leading white space anyways.  `"%lf ,%lf ,%lf"` would scan 0 or more white-space between the number and the following `','`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now while you are accepting the Value the while loops goes fine. But what actually you missed is that you wrote the for Loop inside the While That's why every time it overrides your data.means rather than writing the code:

```
void assign(double A[][COLS], double nrows){
double mass, velocity_terminal, area;
while(scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area)==3){
int i;
for (i= 0; i<nrows; i++){
            A[i][0]= mass;
            A[i][1]= velocity_terminal;
            A[i][2]= area;
}
    }
}
```

You need to write :

```
void assign(double A[][COLS], double nrows){
double mass, velocity_terminal, area;
int i=0;
while(scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area)==3){       
            A[i][0]= mass;
            A[i][1]= velocity_terminal;
            A[i++][2]= area;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're looping mainly on scanf(), but inside every iteration, your for loop sets the las values read to all the elements !

The easiest correction is:

```
   int i=0;    // declare outside the loop and start with first element
   while(scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area)==3 && i<nrows){ // make sure that you don't go out of nrow range
          A[i][0]= mass;
          A[i][1]= velocity_terminal;
          A[i][2]= area;
          i++;
    }
```